# Margin for element in div with display:table-cell moves content in other cell

Tags: css

I have tthe  following simple  layout: http://jsfiddle.net/656ckfyq/

```
  <div class="container">
        <div>
           Some jumping conten  here
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="more">More</a>
        </div>          
   </div>
```

and these are styles for it

```
    .container {
        display: table;
        border: 1px silver solid;
     }

     .container div {
         display: table-cell;
         padding: 10px;
     }

    .more {
        display: block;
        border: 2px red solid;
        margin-top: 20px;
     }
```

So the problem is that I want to  move only link in second cell 20px down. But somehow it also affects content in first cell too.

[image]

So what is the  reason fo this behaviour and how can I  fix this?

Comment: The computed value of `vertical-align` on the 'jumping content' element is bottom. So the content of the cell's bottom edge is aligned with the bottom of the row, which you've pushed down with the `margin` declaration. Playing with that value as documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#column-alignment) should help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `vertical-align: top` property to the table-cells:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px silver solid;
}
.container div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.more {
  display: block;
  border: 2px red solid;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Some jumping content here
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="more">More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```